# Send long SMS and receive it wrong

Tags: android, sms

I'm working on an app that can send sms longer than 160char. I'm testing it on the emulator, using 2 emulators at a time to send the messages between them.

It works fine when sendind, but when receiving it in the other emulator (with android's stock message app) I don't receive exactly what I sent. For example:

If I send the "a" letter more than 160 times, I receive a text with thesame amount of characters, but it starts with the "b" letter and continues with the "c".

Why could be this? This is my code:

```
mSmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
//...

public void onClick(View v) {
            String dest = Uri.parse("sms:" + mDest.getText().toString());
            String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<String> parts = mSmsManager.divideMessage(message);

            mSmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(dest, null, parts, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the emulator does not work correctly sending long message. Test your application on 2 "real" devices, you may not have any problems in the end.